# UIView slide in animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I have a text field inside of a UIView that I want to slide in when the user gets to that VC. Is this easily achievable? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: check out this tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/custom-view-controller-transitions-tutorial/

Comment: Sorry - question was a little unclear with the details.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a quick example:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var textField: UITextField?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        let textFieldFrame = CGRect(x: -200, y: 20, width: 200, height: 30)
        let textField = UITextField(frame: textFieldFrame)
        textField.placeholder = "Some Text"
        self.textField = textField

        self.view.addSubview(self.textField!)

        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: 0.4,
            delay: 0.0,
            options: .curveLinear,
            animations: {

                self.textField?.frame.origin.x = 100

        }) { (completed) in

        }
    }
}
```